# Failed to locate element bind to an iframe

Tags: c#, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate login of following site:
https://www.sbs.com.au/ondemand/

after pressing Signin/Signup its opening login modal which is an iframe.

I am trying to locate email,password, login button with following code but not working. Its opening modal but after that doing nothing just test failing but no error message either.

Code for clicking Signin/signup link and switch to iframe:

```
 var link = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("capture_signin_link"));
        link.Click();
        Driver.Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait.Seconds.Equals(10);
        Driver.Instance.SwitchTo().Frame(1);
```

Code for passing value in email,password,and clicking login button:

```
var inputus = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Name("email"));
        inputus.SendKeys(username);
        Driver.Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait.Seconds.Equals(5);
var inputpass = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Name("password"));
        inputpass.SendKeys(password);
        Driver.Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait.Seconds.Equals(5);

var loginbutton = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.ClassName("traditional-login"));
loginbutton.Click();
```

---

I am not sure if I am passing correct value to find locators and ifame. Please visit above site information for DOM info.
Looking forward a good solution. Please help me

Comment: My latest code worked and its not for ifame locate problem

Answer (score 0):

My Latest Code for clicking signup to open login modal:

```
var link = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("capture_signin_link"));
        link.Click();
        Driver.Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.00);
Driver.Instance.SwitchTo().Frame(Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("login-iframe")));
Driver.Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.00);
```

Code for login:

```
IWebElement inputus = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='onboarding']/div[2]/form/section[2]/div/div[1]/input"));
        inputus.SendKeys(username);

        Driver.Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.00);

        var inputpass = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Name("password"));
        inputpass.SendKeys(password);
        Driver.Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.00);

        var loginbutton = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.ClassName("traditional-login"));
        loginbutton.Click();
```

Above code worked for Chrome. On firefox its showing "Array out of index error" on Sendkeys() method. I found on some blog a lot of people are facing same problem and suggesting to downgrade firefox browser version to get proper support from getco driver as getco driver failing to handle sendkeys().
I haven't try above suggestion. Will try and update here. Till then if you have any other suggestion on that plz let me know.